# How to select column value based upon time difference from consecutive date time column value?

Tags: sql

I have a requirement in SQL, where I have to select sample value when it is greater than 70 in every 20-minute duration. But in my table Date and time value available in consecutive data and time format in one column. Please check sample table view.

```
sampleTime                            SampleValue
2017-04-22 09:00:00.000               65.11
2017-04-22 09:10:00.000               74.09
2017-04-22 10:20:00.000               69.69
2017-04-22 10:30:11.000               90.81
2017-04-22 10:40:09.000               75.55
2017-04-22 10:50:09.000               80.27
2017-04-22 11:00:09.000               45.91
2017-04-22 11:10:09.000               89.55
2017-04-22 11:20:09.000               77.27
2017-04-22 11:30:09.000               75.91
2017-04-22 11:40:09.000               99.55
2017-04-22 11:50:09.000               74.27
2017-04-22 10:22:09.000               75.91
```

expected result :-

```
2017-04-22 09:00:00.000               65.11
2017-04-22 10:20:00.000               69.69
2017-04-22 11:00:09.000               45.91
```

Comment: With that sample data, what is the expected result? What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: sample table is for approx 35 min, out of this i want to select sample value in first 20 min only when samplevalue is less than than 70.

Comment: Edit your question and specify the expected result as formatted text. (Same way as the current sample data!)

Comment: edited , please let me know if you can help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i am using MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sampleTime, SampleValue FROM YourTable
WHERE sampleTime >= '2017-04-22 09:47:05.000' AND sampleTime <= '2017-04-22 10:12:09.000'
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply but in this we are not checking 20-minute duration , i cant hard code it.

Comment: If you dont want to hardcode the 20 minutes every time you can try using DATEADD(minutes, 20, ' date value' )